# Travis config for deploying a static site without any build actions

Tags: amazon-s3, travis-ci

I'd like to use Travis to push a static HTML/JavaScript website to an Amazon S3 bucket on each commit to `master`. Is there any way to configure my `.travis.yml` so it doesn't try to run any sort of build process? Just a deploy?

It seems like this is mainly controlled by the `language` setting which defaults to Ruby, so Ruby is being (unnecessarily) installed on each build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how the ruby box works (I use the java box for my work); that being said, I think that the travis CI boxes have their base language already installed so you aren't really unnecessarily installing ruby each time.

If you want, there supposedly is an [undocumented option](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4895#issuecomment-150703192) `language: generic`.

This way you can just run the required bash commands to deploy your code to Amazon S3

Comment: Great find, thanks! I had been using `language: c` which also seemed pretty minimal, but `generic` sounds like more what I'm after.